# How to calculate radius of convergence of the following series?

Tags: complex-analysis, convergence-divergence

How can I calculate radius of convergence of the following series?

$$\Large
\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty \frac{5^{n+1}}{\sqrt[n]{(2n)!}}z^{n}
$$

I tried using D'alembert convergence test but cannot figure out how to calculate.

I know the answer is $\LARGE\frac{1}{5}$

Comment: The Cauchy-Hadamard formula yields the radius quickly.

Comment: Thank you for your comment.
I think I got right answer.

Comment: @HitoshiOtsuki: If you can post an answer to the question yourself, it is aways welcome here.

Comment: This is what I have got.
$$
1\le((2n)!)^{\frac{1}{n^2}}\le((2n)^{2n})^{\frac{1}{n^2}} = (2n)^{\frac{2}{n}}＝2^{\frac{2}{n}}n^{\frac{2}{n}}\xrightarrow{\scriptscriptstyle n\to\infty}1
$$
Therefore
$$
\sqrt[n]{\frac{5^{n+1}}{\sqrt[n]{(2n)!}}} 
=\frac{5^{\frac{n+1}{n}}}{((2n)!)^{\frac{1}{n^2}}}
\xrightarrow{\scriptscriptstyle n\to\infty} \frac{5}{1}
$$
Hence,by the Cauchy-Hadamard formula, the radius of convergence is $\frac{1}{5}$.

Comment: Looks good! I think @canaaerus suggested you post this as an answer and accept it, though.

Comment: @HitoshiOtsuki What Jonathan Y. said. It's right, and post that as an answer.

Comment: It says,"Users with less than 10 reputation can't answer their own question for 8 hours after asking. You can answer 2/13/2014 8:45:28 PM. Until then please use comments, or edit your question instead". So I will post it later.

Comment: @HitoshiOtsuki: I gave you an up-vote. You should be able to post it now ;-)

Comment: @canaaerus, thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what I have got.
$$
1\le((2n)!)^{\frac{1}{n^2}}\le((2n)^{2n})^{\frac{1}{n^2}} = (2n)^{\frac{2}{n}}＝2^{\frac{2}{n}}n^{\frac{2}{n}}\xrightarrow{\scriptscriptstyle n\to\infty}1
$$
Therefore
$$
\sqrt[n]{\frac{5^{n+1}}{\sqrt[n]{(2n)!}}} 
=\frac{5^{\frac{n+1}{n}}}{((2n)!)^{\frac{1}{n^2}}}\xrightarrow{\scriptscriptstyle n\to\infty}\frac{5}{1}
$$
Hence, by the Cauchy-Hadamard formula, the radius of convergence is $\frac{1}{5}$.

Answer (score 1):

By Stirling's formula,
$$(2n!)^{1/n^2} \sim \left({(2n)^{2n}\over e^{2n}\sqrt{4\pi n}}\right)^{1/n^2
}\sim {(2n)^{2/n}\over e^{2/n} } \rightarrow 1 $$
as $n\to\infty$.  So the radius of convergence is 1/5.